# Maven web resources question

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, resources

I have a Maven web project and I have some CSS and Javascript files under the src\main\webapp\ folder. I constantly make changes to those files and would like to see my changes quickly. If I run *maven install*, it takes ages due to project dependencies. Sometimes all I want to change is one line of code in my CSS file and do not want to recompile everything else. I have a maven plugin that publishes my output war file to my JBoss instance. Ideally, I would like to run a maven execution script that will quickly copy my web resources to the output folder and reploy the changed war file without recompiling everything else.

I tried invoking the *generate-resources* goal but that doesn't seem to look in the src\main\webapp directory as it is expecting my resources to be under the src\main\resources folder. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add more resources to be copied during the generate-resources plugin, you can change the resources folders used by your build.  The `project.build.resources` property controls which folders are searched for resources.  You could add:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webApp</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*.css</include>
          <include>*.js</include>
```

You would then run `mvn resources` to copy the files.

This approach is that these files will always be copied during the resources phase of any build.  You can get around this by using the `copy-resources` goal instead of resources.  In this case you would use the following configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-web-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webApp</outputDirectory>
              <resources> 
                <resource>
                 <directory>src/main/webApp</directory>
                 <includes>
                   <include>*.css</include>
                   <include>*.js</include>
```

You could then run `mvn resources:copy-resources` to copy the files.

Comment: Thank you for that. I tried the configuration you provided for the copy-resources goal but I am getting this error when I execute resources:copy-resources: "The parameters 'resources', 'outputDirectory' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:copy-resources are missing or invalid". Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: I would have to see your configuration.  I don't see any errors in what I have there just by looking at it.

Comment: nevermind that. I think it just didn't like the *.css format for some reason! I modified it to <include>css/**</include> and it is happy with that... odd!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could accomplish this by using the `war:war` goal.  This should generate a war file in the output folder for you without re-compiling the source.

Comment: Actually, unfortenately, that didn't copy the change to my resource. I tried it twice with two different resources that I modified and the changes were not carried through to the output folder or war file.
Is there no way to be selective in what gets re-copied to the war file? The war:war goal takes like 5 min to run for me because there is a large resource folder that it re-copies over everytime eventhough it has not changed. Sometimes I am working on a CSS file and want to keep making changes until I am happy with what I see. I don't think this delay is ideal in such cases. Any more ideas?